# Feed Forward Network Trying to solve by hand

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I am trying to solve the above feed forward network with 1 i/p layer, 1 hidden layer and one output. Activation function is sigmoid. No using bias. Trying to solve forward pass, then back propagation and then again one more forward pass. target is 0.5. can someone explain solving on paper how to approach this problem. Thanks[image]

Comment: Did you able to execute the fw pass?

Comment: yes i did forward pass, back prop i'm unable to do